# Is there something like an `ILIKE` method in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used to do this with an array condition inside the `where` method:

```
Article.where('title ILIKE ?','%today%')
```

This worked in Postgres but `ILIKE` is not present in MySQL and other DBMS.

What I need is to be able to perform case insensitive queries using a code like

```
Article.ilike(title:'%today%',author:'%john%')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if there's not builtin method to perform case insensitive queries, you can use the Arel library and the `matches` method, like in:

```
Article.where(Article.arel_table[:title].matches('%today%'))
```

This is DB agnostic and SQL Injection proof.

I've written an `ilike` method in my common scope file, that allows you to call it with a list of attributes and values, that's it:

```
module CommonScopes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def ilike( options={} )
      raise ArgumentError unless options.is_a? Hash or options.empty?
      if options.one?
       where(arel_table[options.keys.first].matches(options.values.first))
      else
        key, value = options.shift
        ilike( {key=>value} ).merge( ilike( options ) )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can place this inside app/models/concerns/common_scopes.rb and include where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. You need to write driver-specific SQL to achieve this.

ActiveRecord's goal is to make database access fast and easy for 90% of usecases, *not* to make your models completely database-agnostic. Switching your entire database backend from one system to another is not something they optimize for.

You might consider looking at another gem like [DataMapper](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core) which provides a Ruby-syntax for wrapping things like `like` (but which may or may not provide an equivalent to `ilike`):

```
# If the value of a pair is an Array, we do an IN-clause for you.
Person.all(:name.like => 'S%', :id => [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ])
```

Answer (score -2):

Rails don't have the direct case sensitive search. It's dependent on the DB level. For MySQL you can use `LOWER` method.

```
YourModel.where('lower(column_name) = ?', str.downcase)
```

Comment: This is straight equality, which is not at all what `like` or `ilike` do.

Comment: the lower part is correct though. instead of a downvote it couldve just been edited to `lower(column_name) like ?`

Comment: and i'm only necro bumping because this is the only answer that uses a DB query to get the result instead of grabbing all the records and parsing them manually